# Difference in C logical operators

Tags: c

I've come across the `iso646.h` which provides some of the nice logical keyword operators that I'm used to from python. Is one of the following approaches preferred over the other?

```
if (x>7 && y<-2)
    printf("Normal symbols\n");
```

```
#include<iso646.h>
if (x > 7 and z < 4)
     printf("Iso646 is here\n");
```

Is there ever a place where one form would be preferred over the other? Or is this like the `bool` type which is a nice way to replace doing `int is_valid=1;` ?

Comment: Most people don't bother with the names from `<iso646.h>`.  C++ has the names built-in as keywords.  I believe it was added to C for compatibility (or maybe C++ added them for compatibility with C).  The `!` operator may be awkward on some EBCDIC (IBM mainframe) systems.  However, there's no major downside to using them other than their unfamiliarity to the average C coder.

Comment: From [Alternative operators and tokens](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_alternative): "*To be able to use character encodings where some or all of these symbols do not exist*". No good reason to use them, unless you expect your source code to be converted to some unusual encoding that does not cover the ASCII set.

Comment: See the C99 [Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) for more information.  Search for either `iso646.h` or `MSE.4` to find the information.

Comment: The `bool` type (from `<stdbool.h>`, along with `true` and `false`) is more widely used (by far) than the `<iso646.h>` alternative operator names.  Note that the alternative spellings are addressing the same problem that trigraphs and digraphs also address — that C uses a wide vocabulary of punctuation symbols, and some of those symbols are not available in some codesets for non-American languages.

Comment: note that the `bool` type is not merely a nice way to replace `int is_valid = 1;` - it behaves completely differently from any other integer type w.r.t. value conversion! The `bool is_valid = something;` would be more analogous to `int is_valid = !!(something);` - or `int is_valid = not not (something);` to keep the theme of the question

Comment: Then there's `int *p = bitand x;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a C developer, I would be puzzled if I see `and` instead of `&&`. Or should it be a single `&`? I would need to dig into the include files to be sure how that uncommon keyword is defined.

Indeed `&&` is much more familiar than `and` in the context of a C program.

Answer (score 1):

Very few are aware that iso646.h even exists, so therefore it is a bad idea to use it. C programmers are simply not used to the alternative syntax.

This is kind of in the same category as digraphs and trigraphs: strange stuff that arguably should never have been added to the language. The rationale for it all boils down to various locale-specific keyboards. I suppose it is possible that you'll see iso646.h, digraphs or trigraphs actually used in specific countries.